# I am writing a method but i get error expected an indented block

Tags: python

I am practicing writing to a csv file Python 2.7
I had my code working but i am trying to move some of it into a method using def
I get the error:

```
write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
               ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know the indenting is wrong, i have tried using tab and move the lines in but don't know which line and how much to indent.  The error still shows.

My code snippet is:

```
def writeTo_csv():
""""""
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',       quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    write_to_csv.writerow(['id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
fake = Factory.create()
create_fake_stuff(fake)
writeTo_csv()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is messed up for your def:

should be ...

```
def writeTo_csv():
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        write_to_csv.writerow(['id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,'])
```

and also with your main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fake = Factory.create()
    create_fake_stuff(fake)
    writeTo_csv()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def writeTo_csv():
    """""" # if you don't want a docstring remove       
    # indent 
    with open('address_base_test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        write_to_csv.writerow(['id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
     fake = Factory.create() # indent
     create_fake_stuff(fake)
     writeTo_csv()
```

You also have the commas separating the strings inside the quotes so it is going to be treated as a single string which may or not be what you want, if you want a single string you can write it as one:

```
['id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,'] # <- no commas between string

In [45]: print 'id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,'
id,TITLE,FNAME,SNAME,
```

It is equivalent to `'id,TITLE,FNAME,SNAME,GENDER,'`

Comment: ...and also the lines that follow `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: actually his """""" ... will work just fine ... I see why you made the remark though

Comment: @JoshEngelsma, yes but rather futile. I presumed it was an attempt at a docstring which unless it is a single line should be on separate lines, I just left as is

Comment: @RiazLadhani, no worries, unless you plan on inserting a docstring you don't need the """"""

Comment: Agreed, It is rather pointless unless you want a multi-line string, I was just saying that his code would still work without changing it

Comment: What does the 45 do?  Is it the index of the list variable? In [45]: print 'id,' 'TITLE,' 'FNAME,' 'SNAME,' 'GENDER,'

Comment: @RiazLadhani, no sorry that is the  Ipython shell output you are seeing